# How to pause or remove sounds in manim?

Tags: python, manim

I am doing animations in manim ...
I know if you write:

> self.add_sound("name_file.mp3")

the name_file.mp3 will play but if at some point of the animation I'd like to pause the music or remove it
How can I do it?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Short Answer: At this time, Manim doesn't support pausing or stopping the sound file.

Manim only supports adding a complete sound file to the animation.  If you need the sound file edited in any way other than a simple adjustment of the gain (which is a single setting that is applied to the entire sound clip), then you will have to do so outside of Manim.